# iPhone XS the display works but not the touch

Tags: iphone, screen, digitizer

I tried to turn on my iPhone XS; I succeeded but now that I have closed it again the display works but not the touch.

It doesn't matter where I touch, it doesn't work. The rest of the phone works, however.

What could it be?

Comment: Connect it to a Mac/PC and do a backup.  After that, do a [hard restart](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios) and see if that helps.  If that doesn't fix it, you should take it back to Apple or an authorized service location to look at it.

Comment: How can I do a hard reset if I can't unlock the iphone? It says scroll up to unlock the iphone and the touch doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

There are only two pathways to address this:

1. Reset your phone.  Obviously, you need to make sure you have a backup of your data.
2. You need to take it in for service.  The Apple employee will actually repeat step one (and inform you about making a backup as well).

The digitizer (the portion that detects touch input) has died.  Unfortunately, it's no longer a separate components, but it's now glued to the LCD (the portion that displays images).  The whole assembly will need to be replaced.

There is a possibility that the logic board malfunctioned and the digitizer and display is still good, but without opening it up and putting hands on, it's impossible to tell - you still have to take it in.

Comment: Thanks Allan, how can I reset the phone if i can't unlock it with the touch?

Comment: Use iTunes:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

Comment: Ok reset as new, I am stuck on the "hello" screen as i can't swipe up... Everything else seems to be working except the touch

Comment: That's why you have to take it in (path #2).  The reset brought it back to factory where the touch is supposed to work.  If it's not (as yours isn't) it's a *physical hardware issue* and must be replaced.